# Use Google Maps and addMarker with TaskSync?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

how can I use Google Maps and add marker with TaskSync? I have an error:

```
01-23 12:11:26.226: E/AndroidRuntime(1878): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 12:11:26.226: E/AndroidRuntime(1878):     at com.example.maps3.MainActivity$MiTareaAsincronaDialog.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:155)
```

Thanks

**main.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    latitud = 40.42;
    longitud = -3.688889;

    mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapa)).getMap();
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
            new LatLng(latitud, longitud)).zoom(18).build();
    mapa.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    mapa.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    pintarRuta();

    btnAsyncDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAsyncDialog);

    btnAsyncDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setMessage("Procesando...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.setMax(100);

            tarea2 = new MiTareaAsincronaDialog();
            tarea2.execute();
        }
    });
}

public void pintarRuta() {

    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    LatLng point = new LatLng(latitud, longitud);           

    markerPoints.add(point);

    tarea2 = new MiTareaAsincronaDialog();
    tarea2.execute();       
}

private void tareaLarga(){
    try { 
        Thread.sleep(1000); 
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
}

private class MiTareaAsincronaDialog extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            tareaLarga();
            publishProgress(i*10);

            if(isCancelled()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        int progreso = values[0].intValue();

        pDialog.setProgress(progreso);

        mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(point)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
        .title("Posición inicial 1"));

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                MiTareaAsincronaDialog.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });

        pDialog.setProgress(0);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result){
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tarea finalizada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: double click this line '01-23 12:11:26.226: E/AndroidRuntime(1878):     at com.example.maps3.MainActivity$MiTareaAsincronaDialog.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:155)' and see where it takes you, that's giving null pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your  `pintarRuta()` function. You are executing the `MiTareaAsincronaDialog()` asynctask from this function, but the `progressDialog` instance is not available to it at that time because you are making the progressDialog instance on click of `btnAsyncDialog` button. the solution will be to initialize the progressDialog in `onCreate()`:

```
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pDialog.setMessage("Procesando...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.setMax(100);
    pintarRuta();

    btnAsyncDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAsyncDialog);

    btnAsyncDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            tarea2 = new MiTareaAsincronaDialog();
            tarea2.execute();
        }
    });
```

Or in the asynctask's `onPreExecute()`.

Comment: Ok. it works ok. Where you recommend putting my pintarruta () method and pDialog?

Comment: @user3092292 If it works then you can accept it as the answer and if you are initializing the progressDialog in the asyncTask's onPreExecute(), then you can put your pintarruta in the onCreate() itself.

Comment: yes, yes. it run ok. Mi question is if it is the correct site?

Comment: @user3092292 yes, it is ok

Comment: This was added as an edit, should be a comment: **EDIT:**

And I can make a progressDialog in real time and non-fiction?

Comment: @user3092292 you should accept the answer that solved your question and (click the little grey tick so it turns green).

Answer (score 0):

Write the progressdialog initialization code inside your `onPreExecute` not in `onClick` as below:

```
 protected void onPreExecute() {

       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setMessage("Procesando...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
       pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            MiTareaAsincronaDialog.this.cancel(true);
        }
    });

    pDialog.setProgress(0);
    pDialog.show();
}
```